# webkitRequestFullScreen fails when passing Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT in Safari 5.1.2

Tags: javascript, safari, fullscreen

Running into the following problem specifically in Safari 5.1.2 when attempting to use the javascript fullscreen api.

By copy and pasting the following lines into your browser on a loaded page, you can see the effect.

This works in Chrome 15 and Safari 5.1.2:

```
 javascript:document.querySelector('body').webkitRequestFullScreen();
```

This works in Chrome 15 but fails silently in Safari 5.1.2:

```
 javascript:document.querySelector('body').webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
```

ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT seems like it should work in Safari, according to documentation here: http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/WebKit/Reference/ElementClassRef/Element/Element.html

Any ideas why this isn't working?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is known Safari bug. It can be sniffed during full screen switching:

```
someElement.webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
if (!document.webkitCurrentFullScreenElement) {
    // Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT does not work, document is not in full screen mode
}
```

Use this real time sniffing and thus your code will support future fixing bug in Safari.

Comment: I have to timeout the `webkitCurrentFullScreenElement` property read for at least 80ms in Chrome, before that it's null (seems related to the animation Chrome uses for going fullscreen). Isn't there something I can check directly?

Comment: There is `document.webkitIsFullScreen` but I tested and it also requires a timeout before it turns to true in Chrome. However Chrome doesn't really require sniffing because it goes full screen regardless.

Answer (score 3):

`someElement.webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT)` works in chrome.

And `someElement.webkitRequestFullScreen()` works in safari 5.1.7

All test base on windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same issue, and this is most definitely a bug.

This may be a case of [the Undetectables](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/Undetectables). Guess we're gonna have to use good ol' browser sniffing.

```
...(/Safari/.test(navigator.userAgent) ? undefined : Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT)
```

[edit] ...in which case keyboard input isn't possible. So I guess it's best to cut out fullscreen mode in Safari for the time being [/edit]

<sub>Keep in mind that the fullscreen API is in a very early stage at the moment, and should not be used in production</sub>